# TextFormField width issue in mobile device view of Flutter web

Tags: android, flutter

I'm developing a PWA based web application on the flutter web. But the issue is in My Login page TextFormField not displaying properly. It takes width only half of the total width of the screen. I want to display TextFormField with full width. Please Help me.I'm Stuck.

[image]

My code is...

//How can I solve this?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String username = "";
  String password = "";
  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> sKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      key: sKey,
      primary: false,
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      body: Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        children: <Widget>[
          SafeArea(
            child: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
              alignment: Alignment.topRight,
              child: InkWell(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 16, 16, 16),
                  child: IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.arrow_forward,
                      color: Color(0xf0166EB8),
                    ),
                    onPressed: null,
                  ),
                ),
                onTap: () {
//                  if (state.isLoading) return;
//                  gotoHome();
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Center(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                child: Form(
                  key: _formKey,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        "User Login",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.grey,
                            fontSize: 26,
                            letterSpacing: 4,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "Green buildings can save up to 40% of their energy requirements.",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.grey,
                            letterSpacing: 3,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 60,
                      ),
                      Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            TextFormField(
                              textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                labelText: "User name",
                              ),
                              // ignore: missing_return
                              validator: (String value) {
                                if (value.isEmpty) {
                                  return "User name is required.";
                                }
                              },
                              onSaved: (value) {
                                username = value;
                              },
                              onFieldSubmitted: (value) {},
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 16,
                            ),
                            TextFormField(
                              obscureText: true,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                labelText: "Password",
//                                          border: OutlineInputBorder()
                              ),
                              validator: (String value) {
                                if (value.isEmpty) {
                                  return "Password is required.";
                                }
                              },
                              onSaved: (value) {
                                password = value;
                              },
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 16,
                            ),
                            RaisedButton(
                              elevation: 16,
                              shape: CircleBorder(),
                              child: IconButton(
                                onPressed: null,
                                icon: Icon(
                                  Icons.arrow_forward,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                              ),
                              textColor: Colors.white,
                              color: Color(0xf0166EB8),
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
                              onPressed: () {
//                                if (state.isLoading) return;

                                if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                                  _formKey.currentState.save();
//                                            login();
//                                  userLogin(store);
                                }
                              },
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 16,
                      ),
                      InkWell(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                        onTap: () {
//                          gotoRegister();
                        },
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 16, 10),
                          child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Text(
                                "Don't have an account?",
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
                              ),
                              Text(
                                "Create new",
                                style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xf0166EB8)),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
//      ],
//    ));
  }

  void setFocus(FocusNode fromFocus, FocusNode toFocus) {
    fromFocus.unfocus();
    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(toFocus);
  }
}
```

Comment: Wrap it in a container with width = double.infinity.

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: @TinusJackson Wrap it in a container with width = double.infinity.  is not working.

Comment: Hello @PhucTran i added my code. Please give me any solution.

Comment: @Olance can you add more information on how to recreate it. Here is a dartpad with your code which is working fine https://dartpad.dev/b6409e10de32b280b8938aa75364fa7b

Comment: Hello @TinusJackson Just you can try to see this code design in mobile view in developer option.This issue generating only on mobile view.
Also you can check my live site on your physical device to see issue.

Comment: https://flutter-react-native.firebaseapp.com

Comment: I tried your code on my iPhone simulator and it worked. Do you get the issue on web only?

Comment: @PhucTran after upgrading flutter my issue solved.Thanks brother.

Comment: Great to hear! @Olance